# Is static_cast a template?

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning C++ templates, I found that the type conversion like `static_cast<>`, `dynamic_cast<>`, `const_cast<>` and `reinterpret_cast<>` looks like templates, though the book said they are all "operators". I want to know:

1)Whether these cast functions are written by templates?

2)If it is true, Where can I find the source code?

3)If it is not true, why they are all designed in the form of templates? is it possible to implement them by templates?

Comment: No, these are called _cast operators_.

Comment: 1) no. 3) bjarne wanted casts to be ugly

Comment: @sp2danny Could you explain why bjarne wanted casts to be ugly?

Comment: It's true, Bjarne's words were "`reinterpret_cast<int>(p)` is ugly notation for an ugly operation". See [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/devXinterview.html)

Answer (score 5):

> Whether these cast functions are written by templates?

No. As your book says, they're operators.

> why they are all designed in the form of templates?

Like templates, their behaviour is partly specified using a compile-time type parameter. It makes sense to use the same syntax to do the same thing in a slightly different context.

> is it possible to implement them by templates?

Using just the core C++ language, no.

It's possible that `static_cast`, `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` could be implemented by a combination of a C-style cast (which allows all these conversions), and C++11 type traits to restrict the conversions to those allowed in each case. However, some of those traits depend on magic that can't be implemented using the core language.

`dynamic_cast` needs to access the object's RTTI information; there's no way to do that other than through `typeid` or `dynamic_cast` itself.

Answer (score 4):

`static_cast` *etc* are **language keywords** and, as such, are not templates.

They look *like* templates since that's the best functional form to express their functionality.

To an extent you *can* implement functions similar in form to these casts. For example, I define in some of my code a function `integral_cast`:

```
    template<
        typename T/*the desired type*/,
        typename/*the source type*/ Y
    > T integral_cast(const Y& y)
    {
        static_assert(false, "undefined integral_cast");
    }

    // Pass through for uint32_t
    template<>
    inline std::uint32_t integral_cast(const uint32_t& y)
    {
        return y;
    }

    /*and various other specialisations*/
```

This allows me to convert from one integral type to another in situations where I might overflow the destination type. The calling syntax is identical to the built in casts.

Comment: Another notable example is Boost's [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

Comment: Qt's [qobject_cast<>](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) as well.